# Como criar um teste para uma tela que usa o mesmo hook várias vezes? React Testing Library

Tags: react, jest, mock, multiple, render

Me deparei com um cenário de teste em React onde preciso usar um hook duas vezes.
Neste caso estou usando um hook chamado useGet() em duas situações na mesma página.
De todas as vezes que tentei só é mockado o último resultado, deixando o primeiro undefined.
Alguém sabe uma forma de mockar os dois no mesmo teste para eu renderizar o html completo no teste?

Exemplo de variáveis usadas na tela e que precisam ser mockadas:

```
const getBoletoCashIn = useGet('all-boletos-cash-in')
const getBoletoCashOut = useGet('all-boletos-cash-out')

try {
  const getCashIn = await getBoletoCashIn.refetch()
  const getCashOut = await getBoletoCashOut.refetch()
  console.log(getCashIn, getCashOut)
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Tentativa no teste

```
const mockGetData = jest.fn()

jest.mock('@/hooks/useRest', () => {
  return {
    useGet: () => {
      return {
        refetch: mockGetData
      }
    }

  }
})

const customRender = (ui: JSX.Element, { providerProps, ...renderOptions }: { providerProps: { url: { baseUrl: string } } }) => {
  return render(
    <GlobalProvider>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {ui}
    </GlobalProvider>,
    renderOptions
  )
}

describe('Cash-In & Cash-Out chart component', () => {
  it('', async () => {
    const { debug } = customRender(
      <CashInCashOutChart />,
      { providerProps }
    )

    // Array aleatório
    mockGetData.mockImplementationOnce(() => ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
    mockGetData.mockImplementationOnce(() => ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

    await waitFor(() => expect(mockGetData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))

    await waitFor(() => {
      debug()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucionei colocando o `mockImplementationOnce` diretamente neste bloco de código que estava fora do `it()` e removi os que estavam dentro do `it`, deixando apenas o `toHaveBeenNthCalledWith`.

```
jest.mock('@/hooks/useRest', () => {
  return {
    useGet: jest.fn((url) => {
      if (url === 'all-boletos-cash-in') {
        return {
          refetch: mockGetData.mockImplementationOnce(() => [1, 2, 3])
        }
      }
      if (url === 'all-boletos-cash-out') {
        return {
          refetch: mockGetData.mockImplementationOnce(() => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```